# I am trying to read JSON Data then trying to populate that data into a excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried the following code

[Click on this link to get the json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J0EpMnW4HGovVy0MMM2Lk43u9HopROCR/view?usp=sharing)

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_json('C:\\Users\\rajat.kapoor\\Downloads\\comprehensive JSON.json')
df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\rajat.kapoor\\Desktop\\JsonOutput.xlsx')
```

but it is giving

```
 File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py:666, in _extract_index(data)
    664 lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    665 if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 666     raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
    668 if have_dicts:
    669     raise ValueError(
    670         "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."
    671     )

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

I have checked many posts regarding this ValueError but is beyond my comprehension. Would appreciate the solution for the same

Comment: Without your json file (or a sample), we can't help you.

Comment: could you provide a sample of your json data?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. There might be some assumptions made in the libraries used. Also, like the 2 users above me mentioned: show the source data.

Comment: @Corralien i have added the json file that i am using for reading data

Comment: @SakshiGatyan i ahve added json file that i am using

Comment: @JustLudo I have added the Json file, please have a look at it

Comment: So, did you see this? https://www.statology.org/valueerror-all-arrays-must-be-same-length/

Comment: @JustLudo yes i did , but as you can see in the json file we have large amount of data and making sure that each array has the same length when you have this much of a data is difficult task

Comment: The restriction is imposed by Pandas apparently, so either don't use pandas for parsing this file or perhaps split it up into parse-able parts and make it work in another way?

Comment: Which data do you want to load from your json file? (accountProfiles, overallAnalysis, etc)

Comment: @Corralien if possible the whole data from JSON File else overallAnalysis

Comment: And do you want: monthlyAnalytics, weeklyAnalytics, dailyAnalytics or all in 3 different sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import json

data = json.load(open('comprehensive JSON.json'))

# For overallAnalysis
with pd.ExcelWriter('overallAnalysis.xlsx') as writer:
    meta = pd.json_normalize(data['overallAnalysis']).select_dtypes(exclude=object)
    meta.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Metadata', header=False)

    for analytics in ['monthlyAnalytics', 'weeklyAnalytics', 'dailyAnalytics']:
        df = pd.json_normalize(data['overallAnalysis'], analytics)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=analytics, index=False)
```

Comment: I gave an example on how to iterate over a dictionary entry. Is it what you expect? For other entries, you have to adapt this code. There is no generic solution because each entry have a different format :-(